# Using a NULL value to signify that the value does not mattter. Not that it isn't known

Tags: database-design, null

Say I have a table with computers where one column is a boolean "fan". If true the computer has a fan, if false it does not. It can never be null.

Now I have another table with a list of recommendations for improvements to computers.

I want some recommendations to apply to all computers which have a fan. For this I have a column "fan" which when true will only apply to computers with a fan. When false will only apply to computers without a fan.

Is it good database design to have the column set to null when the recommendation should not care if the computer has a fan or not? As in the recommendation should apply whether the computer has a fan or not.

The purpose of null values is that the column is not known. Which is not the case here. It's not that I don't know if the recommendation is for a computer with a fan or without a fan, it's that I specifically don't care either way. This makes me think that it's not a good idea and is just changing the meaning of null.

On the other hand I think it makes sense that if the "fan" filter on the recommendation isn't defined it means that it doesn't need to filter based on that.

The other way to define the recommendation is have a `applies_to_fanned_computers` and `applies_to_not_fanned_computers` columns. If both are true then it applies to either, if only one is true then it applies to one of them.

Which option is best? Am I right that the first option is a bastardization of the purpose of null values in a database?

Comment: No, null doesn't mean unknown. It can mean different things in different contexts. See https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/50-shades-of-null-or-how-a-billion-dollar-mistake-has-been-stalking-a-whole-industry-for-decades/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using NULL for this purpose would overload the value and require the consumer to know this special meaning of NULL.  These are "magic" values and should be avoided.

What you need is more than two values.  If you are concerned about space, use SMALLINT.

You should have the values (at least of):

- NULL - unknown / not specified
- YES - fan is required
- NO - fan is not required
- N/A - not applicable

You can use an enum table to store the mapping, or just use a CHAR(3) field to start off with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jonathan, how come you are you preferring using one column with 3 values over two boolean columns like I suggested in the question?

Comment: using two columns still requires the consumer to intimately know to look at both columns and understand how they relate to another.  Think of it as the difference from reading tea leaves (multiple columns) vs looking up the average atmospheric pressure for a given altitude on earth... basically, the KISS principle.  You can easily expand to additional values as needed.

Comment: I just noticed a small issue with your answer. You say "NO - fan is not required" whilst what I wanted was an option for a fan to not be allowed. As in show the recommendation only on computers without a fan. I suppose the options could be "Fan" "No Fan" and "Any"

Comment: You can add what you need for the available values, but that was what the "N/A" was for.  But my answer was less about possible values and meant to advise against using multiple columns to answer a single question.

Comment: Oh right of course. Sorry, I missunderstood what you meant there. That makes sense

Answer (score 1):

My approach for this is to think of what the fields are, which is storing information on computers. There is no case ever where having a fan would result in NULL, just a yes or no. In your case of using it as a major category for computers, I would avoid that, and instead use your queries and stored procedures to consider the filters. In the stored procedure you can have the WHERE clause look for the different combinations;

Only Computers with fans -- SELECT [recommendations] FROM table WHERE [has_fan]=1

Only computers without fans --SELECT [recommendations] FROM table WHERE [has_fan]=0

All computers\don't care -- don't use a WHERE clause;SELECT [recommendations] FROM table

Comment: Thanks John, I'm not entirely sure I understand the answer, could you please show what the schema would look like under your model?

Also just to clarify, the queries will be on the computer page, where I want to get all recommendations applicable to that computer. So I would want all recommendations which require a fan as well as all recommendations which don't care if I have a fan or not. The options you posted don't seem to cover that case unless I run multiple queries